# How to write a generic mock which maps interface properties to key-value pairs in c# using moq

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, moq

I want to write a method which creates mocks for any interface.

```
public T GetMock<T>(IDictionary<string, object> data) where T : class
```

I care only about property getters first. All getters should return values which are stored in the dictionary. Property name is a key in this dictionary. Following code illustrates intended usage:

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Property1 { get; }
        int Property2 { get; }
        DateTime Property3 { get; }
    }


    [Test]
    public void TestY()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"Property1", "Hello"},
            {"Property2", 5},
            {"Property3", DateTime.Today}
        };

        var mock = GetMock<IFoo>(data);

        Assert.AreEqual("Hello", mock.Property1);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, mock.Property2);
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Today, mock.Property3);
    }
```

The point is that I want to mock ANY interface. So my generic mock crreation looks like:

```
    public T GetMock<T>(IDictionary<string, object> data) where T : class
    {
        var mock = new Mock<T>();
        var type = typeof(T);
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var attributeName = property.Name;
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
            var body = Expression.Property(parameter, attributeName);
            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
            Func<object> getter = () => data[attributeName];
            mock.Setup(lambdaExpression).Returns(getter);
        }
        return mock.Object;
    }
```

It should work but there is an issue with type conversion. The test fails with a message:

> System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be
>   used for return type 'System.Object'

I guess I am missing some conversion lambda. Any suggestions how to fix the problem?

Comment: What line gives you that exception? `var lambdaExpression...` ?

Comment: Exactly. The line `var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);`

Comment: I expect it's because you're trying to return an (e.g.) `int` parameter from a `Func<T, object>`, but I'm sorry I don't know how to fix it :p

Comment: That's exactly my guess too.

Answer (score 1):

Guess the only option is to use Reflection, because current version is 4.2, but still - there's no "Mock.Setup(Expression expr)" implementation, as stated Patrick.
So, here's my sample:

```
    public static class ConfigFactory<T> where T : class {
    static T cachedImplInstance;

    public static T BuildConfigGroupWithReflection() {
        if (cachedImplInstance == null) {
            Type interfaceType = typeof(T);
            MethodInfo setupGetMethodInfo = typeof(Mock<T>).GetMethod("SetupGet");
            Mock<T> interfaceMock = new Mock<T>();

            IDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> genericSetupGetMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
            IDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> specificReturnsMethodInfos = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

            if (setupGetMethodInfo != null)
                foreach (PropertyInfo interfaceProperty in interfaceType.GetProperties()) {
                    string propertyName = interfaceProperty.Name;
                    Type propertyType = interfaceProperty.PropertyType;

                    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(interfaceType);
                    MemberExpression body = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
                    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);

                    MethodInfo specificSetupGetMethodInfo =
                        genericSetupGetMethodInfos.ContainsKey(propertyType) ?
                        genericSetupGetMethodInfos[propertyType] :
                        genericSetupGetMethodInfos[propertyType] = setupGetMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);

                    object setupResult = specificSetupGetMethodInfo.Invoke(interfaceMock, new[] { lambdaExpression });
                    MethodInfo returnsMethodInfo = 
                        specificReturnsMethodInfos.ContainsKey(propertyType) ?
                        specificReturnsMethodInfos[propertyType] :
                        specificReturnsMethodInfos[propertyType] = setupResult.GetType().GetMethod("Returns", new[] { propertyType });

                    if (returnsMethodInfo != null)
                        returnsMethodInfo.Invoke(setupResult, new[] { Settings.Default[propertyName] });
                }                
            cachedImplInstance = interfaceMock.Object;
        }
        return cachedImplInstance;
    }
}
```

Notice line "returnsMethodInfo.Invoke(setupResult, new[] { Settings.Default[propertyName] });" - you may put your dictionnary here.

Say, we have interface:

```
public interface IConfig {
    string StrVal { get; }
    int IntVal { get; }

    StringCollection StrsVal { get; }

    string DbConnectionStr { get; }

    string WebSvcUrl { get; }
}
```

Then, usage is as follows (assuming we have "Settings" of our project with corresponding Names/Types/Values):

```
IConfig cfg0 = ConfigFactory<IConfig>.BuildConfigGroupWithReflection();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a half answer, since I don't see any support in Moq for doing this.  To get the correct `Func`, do the following:

```
// In your for loop from above...
var attributeName = property.Name;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
var body = Expression.Property(parameter, attributeName);

// Add this line to create the correct Func type
var func = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), property.PropertyType);

// Then use this Func to create the lambda
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(func, body, parameter);
```

The problem is that `Setup` doesn't have an overload that allows you to pass in a non-generic expression that represents a `Func`.  In otherwords, this won't compile:

```
// Error: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' 
//        to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action<T>>' 
mock.Setup(lambdaExpression);
```

So at this point you're stuck.

You could submit an issue (or pull request) to the [Moq project](https://github.com/Moq/moq), though I don't know if this application has a wide enough audience...